# How can we show name with face id from azure face api?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-recognition, face-api

i have a persongroup where i have stored all users id and name. I looked into the azure documentation about face api but i didn't got anything for showing the name according to face id. Before a while i used to store the name and id in a different python file from where i used to show the name. But then i thought we already store the name and id in azure why to create another file and store the data for 2 times instead of that showing the name directly from face api. Can anyone guide me to how to show the name with id?

```
def face_identify(faceId):
    global person
    KEY = parser.get('AzCognitiveServices','Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key')
 

    headers = {
        # Request headers
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': KEY,
    }

    params = urllib.urlencode({
    })


    if faceId is None:
        person = ""
        return

    group = parser.get('AzCognitiveServices','PersonGroupId')
    candidatesreturned = list(parser.get('AzCognitiveServices','maxNumOfCandidatesReturned'))
    threshold = parser.get('AzCognitiveServices','confidenceThreshold')

        
    body = "{'personGroupId' : '" + group + "','faceIds' : [%s],'maxNumOfCandidatesReturned' : 1,'confidenceThreshold': 0.5}" % str("'%s'"%faceId)
    logger.info(body)
    
    try:
        uri_base = parser.get('AzCognitiveServices','BaseURL')
        path_to_face_api = "/face/v1.0/identify"
        response = requests.post(uri_base + path_to_face_api,
                                 data=body,
                                 headers=headers,
                                 params=params,timeout=int(parser.get('AzCognitiveServices','Timeout')))
                       
        #response = conn.getresponse()
        data = response.json()
        logger.info('face id %s',data)
    
        candidates = data[0]["candidates"]
        
        if len(candidates) > 0:
            person = str(candidates[0]["personId"])
        else:
            person = ""

        print(person)
    except Exception as e:
        print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the name of your persons when you create those items, you just have to get your PersonGroup by id when you have found a person.

So in your code, it is at this step:

```
person = str(candidates[0]["personId"])
```

Here you have the personId of the found person. Use it with the GET method from the PersonGroup Person, see documentation [here](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523f). It needs your PersonGroupId and PersonId.

You will retrieve the name you are looking for